# Trying to configure Lubuntu 18.10 to install via PXE Tftp

Tags: pxe

Get error message halfway through it fails to download a file from mirror even though all files are there.
Do you have a better ISO or configuration guide for PXE configuration

Comment: Hi Don, can you share anymore details on the error?

Comment: I am using A bee-link mini PC as a target and it seems to always have the issue I have tried other min PC and some work but all seem to fail or hang halfway mark it just stops